# Devops and AWS Lambda Functions Tools

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, devops, devops-services

We use Codepipeline from AWS to automatize all the deployment process for most of our services and workers.

Everyday we use more lambda functions and microservices in our company but is getting hard to manage the deployment of them.

Anyone has experience with CI/CD tools to manage a couple of dozens of microservices in production and development ?

I never use Codepipeline for Lambda, so maybe is an option that I did not see, but I am not close to use any other tools as an option.

Any recommendations ?. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end the best solution that worked for us was connecting Github and TravisCI to automatize all the deployment of the lambda functions. I hope that this answer also help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

For managing lambdas (and in general serverless technologies in AWS) I would recommend the [Serverless Application Model (SAM)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html), which allows you (for example) to version control and review your lambda architecture; essentially you define your configuration in a YAML file, then bundle this together with the code for all your lambda functions, and deploy to cloudformation where it builds the architecture from the template.

This should integrate with other AWS services so you can trigger builds/deployments etc.

[Github page with source and readme etc](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md)